# Instagram oAuth: "Invalid scope field(s)" (only using Firefox browser)

Tags: firefox, instagram

I cannot get my access token for Instagram using **Firefox**. There is an error `"Invalid scope field(s): public_content,follower_list"`. But it works in other browsers like Google Chrome or Safari.

I throw this URL from my web client https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIEND&redirect_uri=https://MY_REDIRECT&response_type=code&scope=public_content+follower_list. 
And looks like there is an encoding problem.
From the Instagram documentation: `If you’d like to request multiple scopes at once, simply separate the scopes by a space`. 
So, I've tried to use `public_content follower_list`, `public_content+follower_list`, `public_content%2Bfollower_list` but it  doesn't work in Firefox =\ 
Any ideas? Thanks for advance!

Comment: Maybe it's a temporary Instagram error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These scopes are deprecated. Use the "basic" instead.